# Django raw query being executed more times than expected

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a raw sql query done in Django and a test to make sure the number of queries being executed is down to 1. The problem is that my iterations checking the returned objects trigger duplicate calls to that raw query.

```
class CategoryManager:
    ....

    @staticmethod
    def get_by_popularity():
        return Category.objects.raw( """.........""" )




class CategoryManagerTestCase( TestCase ):
    ....

    with self.assertNumQueries( 1 ):
        categories = CategoryManager.get_by_popularity( )

        for c in categories:
            if c.name == root_cat.name:
                self.assertEqual( c.visitors_count, 14 )

        #   when I add this second iteration the query gets executed a second time
        for c in categories:
            self.assertTrue( hasattr( c, 'id' ) )
            self.assertTrue( hasattr( c, 'name' ) )
            self.assertTrue( hasattr( c, 'parent_id' ) )
            self.assertTrue( hasattr( c, 'description' ) )
            self.assertTrue( hasattr( c, 'visitors_count' ) )
            self.assertTrue( hasattr( c, 'projects_count' ) )
```

Comment: If you convert the result to a `list`, you will prevent the additional query: `categories = list(CategoryManager.get_by_popularity( )`

Comment: That works. Any idea what it was causing it? Can you add it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the result to a list, you will prevent the additional query:

```
categories = list(CategoryManager.get_by_popularity())
```

Or you might want to return a list from your method instead:

```
@staticmethod
def get_by_popularity():
    return list(Category.objects.raw( """.........""" ))
```

If the query was `Category.objects.filter(...)` instead of raw, then looping through the queryset multiple times would only cause it to be fetched once.

However Django doesn't cache the results of the raw queryset. The warning [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) suggests that caching hasn't been added for backwards compatibility reasons.

> While a `RawQuerySet` instance can be iterated over like a normal `QuerySet`, `RawQuerySet` doesn’t implement all methods you can use with `QuerySet`. For example, `__bool__()` and `__len__()` are not defined in `RawQuerySet`, and thus all `RawQuerySet` instances are considered `True`. The reason these methods are not implemented in `RawQuerySet` is that implementing them without internal caching would be a performance drawback and adding such caching would be backward incompatible.

Comment: It's crazy not to support something sooo important because of backward incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately raw queries are [evaluated every time they are iterated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/)

> While a RawQuerySet instance can be iterated over like a normal
>   QuerySet, RawQuerySet doesn’t implement all methods you can use with
>   QuerySet. For example, **bool**() and **len**() are not defined in
>   RawQuerySet, and thus all RawQuerySet instances are considered True.
>   The reason these methods are not implemented in RawQuerySet is that
>   implementing them without internal caching would be a performance
>   drawback and adding such caching would be backward incompatible.